# How many dried herbs are mixed with a kilo of tomato sauce?

Tags: sauce

How many tablespoon of dried oregano should be placed for a kilo of tomato sauce for my spaghetti sauce? Please answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no set amount or rule to guide you, as there is a lot of variation in tomato sauce for spaghetti.  Some people use oregano, some use marjoram, some use thyme, some use basil...some use a combination.  Oftentimes fresh herbs are used, rather than dried herbs.  A tablespoon of dried oregano sounds like a lot to me, unless you really like that flavor.  I would start with much less, see how you like the flavor, then add more until it is of your liking.  It is much more difficult to remove or alter the flavor if you start with too much.  I would suggest you begin with a quarter teaspoon and work your way up.

Comment: 1/4 teaspoon for a kilo? Sounds overly cautious to me? But I agree with the principle.

Comment: @Stephie Admittedly, I am not a huge fan of dried oregano in my pasta sauce.  I prefer fresh thyme.  However, a kilo is just a bit more more than a 28oz can of tomatoes (about 35 oz, I believe).  You would certainly perceive the flavor from that amount if it were cooked with other aromatics before adding the tomato.  On the other hand "tablespoons" would be completely overpowering, in my opinion.